# Loop to alter worksheet page setup/print area

Tags: vba, excel

I've got to a point where I have compiled an Excel workbook of multiple sheets from multiple places. The problem is they all have different page setups, print areas etc. Print area is the main thing, so i'm looking to set up a loop in VBA to go through all the sheets in the document and change the print area to "fit on one page". Here Is something I have created and am working on, it runs in VBA but nothing actually happens? :/. Also is there a way to Centralize in the page? So not just fit to page, but fit and center in page?

```
Sub WsLoop()

Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I am almost certain you need to have activate the page to work with `PageSetup`. So place a `ws.Activate` after the `For each ws ...` line. For centering see the `CenterVertically` and `CenterHorizontally` options (set them to `True`)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, will give it a go now and see if it works :) will let you know how it goes soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `.Orientation` works for me in Excel 2010. Your use of
   `ActiveWorkbook` might be the problem; it could be selecting a
   different Workbook than you expected. Try using the workbook name to
   select it.
2. For the `.FitToPagesWide` and `.FitToPagesTall` to work, put the
   following before them: `.Zoom = False`
3. `.CenterHorizontally` and `.CenterVertically` properties of the
   `PageSetUp` object should work without surprises as mentioned by
   Scott

I tried in Excel 2010 and this works. For the `.FitToPagesWide` and `.FitToPagesTall`, you won't see them populated when you just click on "Print" on "File" menu; you'll see them populated if you then click on the "Page Setup" link at the bottom of the pane between the submenu on the left and preview on the right.